# How to style Material UI's Tab component label?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm looking for a way to customize the color of the text inside the `Tab` component but at the same time retaining the ability for it to be colored over when selected as an active Tab.

Example code:

```js
<Tabs centered onChange={handleChange} value={value} textColor={'secondary'} indicatorColor={'secondary'}>
    <Tab label={'Hello There'} style={{color: '#fff'}}/>
    <Tab label={'Hello There'} style={{color: '#fff'}}/>
    <Tab label={'Hello There'} style={{color: '#fff'}}/>
</Tabs>
```

The above code will result in the change of the text color **BUT** when the `Tab` becomes active, it won't be overridden.

If it helps, I'm also using `styled-components` for ease of use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `makeStyles` export of material-ui to create your custom class for the label

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  customLabelColor: {
    color: "#fff"
  }
});

export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    ...
    <Tab
      label={"Hello There"}
      classes={{
        textColorSecondary: classes.customLabelColor
      }}
    />
    ...
  );
}
```

CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-kowalevski-xzf7g?file=/src/App.js

---

Refer [here](https://material-ui.com/api/tab/#css) for other methods on how to override the `CSS` for `Tab`.

On the same reference I linked, have a look at the `textColorSecondary` rule name. This is specific to your question since you are using `textColor="secondary"` on your parent component `Tabs`